# Detect raspberry pi with android smartphone

Tags: pi-3

I would like to find a way to detect a specific Raspberry Pi from an Android smartphone, whenever it gets near the Pi. Background is the following: I want the smartphone to activate a hotspot and connect to the pi via bluetooth when the phone gets in range of the pi, but I want to do so without having bluetooth and/or hotspot on permanently on the phone.

I found an app on the phone that can automate most if not all of the phones part of this, but I need a way for the phone to realize that its near to the pi.

Another way to do this would be to find a way to get the phone to share its mobile data connection with a wifi hotspotr on the pi, but I didn't have much luck finding a way to do that (especially without a rooted phone).

Is there anything I can do on the Pi that would allow the phone to "see" it?

FYI: I am using a Rapberry Pi 3B.

Edit in rsponse to comments:

The Pi will be installed inside my car, so it is not stationary, therefore GPS or similar is not possible. And the car itself does not have anything that would help with that...

@Mr. Panda: That phrase was referring to the phone being the client and the Raspberry Pi being the hotspot. I know that I can connect the Pi to the phones hotspot, but in order to do that automatically, the hotspot would always have to be on, wich is something I don't want as stated above.

Comment: "but I didn't have much luck finding a way to do that (especially without a rooted phone)". Can you elaborate this? I always connect my Pi to my phone's (android) hotspot.

Comment: If the Pi is stationary, can you use GPS?

Comment: If your phone has NFC this would be an option. Just place a NFC tag in your car next to the Pi and use the tag to start an automation task that establishes the connection. Then you just have to "swipe" your phone over the NFC tag to activate the task.

Comment: As I understand this, you want the phone to start WiFi tethering when the Pi is nearby? In that case, this is more an Android/iPhone question than a Pi question. You ay also look at a phone that is able to connect to both 3/4G and WiFi simultaneous and find some routing application. That too is an android/iPhone question.